# Track AVD/genymotion traffic with wireshark?

Tags: android, networking, network-programming, wireshark, traffic

I've faced some issues connecting android AVD/genymotion with local web service and would like to track it. Looking for some tools that could help to define where is the problem and considered the wireshark.

Did you tired that or maybe there's an other way to do it (if tcpdump is simpler..)  properly?

Regards